# Error 500 for retrieved Json img src from database

Tags: c#, json, image, src

I try to display image retrieved from db with some other object values as Json.

I learned that image object is not json serializable, so I changed byte[] to string in class, and pass it as image source.

Ajax POST response, should show image where I call its src src=\"'+photo+'"\"/> in JQuery. When I run the page, I receive Error 500 Internal Server Error in Browsers Console.

Class:

```
//other class values
public string Photo { get; set; }
```

[WebMethod]

```
public static string GetRooms(string arrival, string departure, string nob)
{
    //db connection
 SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); ;
 while (sdr.Read())
{
   Room r = new Room();
  //other values
  b = (byte[])sdr["Photo"];
  r.Photo = "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(b).ToString();

  lst.Add(r);
  val = jSerialize.Serialize(lst);
}}
　
}
 return val;
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "main.aspx/GetRooms",
     data: "{'arrival':'" + arrival + "','departure':'" + departure + "','nob':'" + nob + "'}",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (response) {

             r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d),

             $.each(r, function (k) {
                   var id = this.ID,
                   title = this.RoomTitle,
                   price = this.Price,
                   photo=this.Photo,

                   divItem.append($('<div />', { "class": "row" }).append($('<img src=\"'+photo+'"\"/>', { "class": "h-looks-s" })),
                   //other values appended                     
        );
      });
 },

error: function (result) {
          alert("Failed!");
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: An internal error response suggests there will be an exception logged server-side. You should look at that exception...

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you for your response. Something is wrong at this line in WebMethod: `b= (byte[])sdr['Photo']; r.Photo= "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(b).Tostring();` When I remove this line I don't receive Error. But I really need that line to retrieve images.

Comment: "Something is wrong" really doesn't tell us much... and it certainly doesn't help us know what exception has been logged. If nothing has been logged, that's the first thing you should fix - it's *vital* that you're able to look at errors that are occurring on your server.

Comment: Also, the result of `Convert.ToBase64String` is already a string - so you really don't need to call `ToString()` on it.

Comment: I see now.. error is in WebMethod: `Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.` I set `maxJsonLength` in webconfig file now my code works. Thank you @JonSkeet